# How to return a value of Dictionary that satisfies the given predicate?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, dictionary, filter

I can't solve next problem. I get an array of Dictionaries from JSON with the same keys and different values.
For example:

```
{
        "data": [{
                "name": "Anna",
                "features": {
                    "age": "18",
                    "hobby": "football"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Peter",
                "data": {
                    "age": "16",
                    "hobby": "computer games"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Peter",
                "data": {
                    "age": "25",
                    "hobby": "chess",
                    "job": "fireman"
                }
            }
        ],
        "view": ["Peter", "Anna", "Peter"]
}
```

This is my structures for Decoding:

```
struct Object: Decodable {
    let objectData: [DictionaryData]
    let bjectView: [String]
}

struct DictionaryData: Decodable {
    let name: String
    let features: Features?
    let data: DataClass?
}

struct DataContainer: Decodable {
    let age, hobby: String
    let job: String?
}

struct Features: Decodable {
    let age, hobby: String
}
```

This is the point where I stuck. I use filter but it returns Bool while I need a value of dictionaries:

```
    var items = [ModelItem]()
    var singleObject: Object!

    func jsonParsing(completionHandler: @escaping (([ModelItem], Error?) -> Void)) {

        guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in

            guard let data = data else { DispatchQueue.main.async {completionHandler([], error)}
                return
            }

            do {
                self.singleObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(Object.self, from: data)
                let sequenceArray = self.singleObject.objectView
                for i in sequenceArray {
                    if i == "Peter" {
                        if let objectName = self.singleObject?.objectData.filter({ return $0.name == "Peter"}) ... {
                            let firstItem = ModelFirstItem(text: ...) //here should be a value
                            self.items.append(firstItem)
                        }
                    }
                    else if i == "Anna" {
                        ...
                        }
                    }
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {completionHandler(self.items, nil)}
            } catch {
                print("Error serializing json:", error)
            }
            } .resume()
    }
```

How can I get age, hobby and job values?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried decode your son using `Decodable` and `JSONDecoder`?

Comment: It's already decoded :)
It's just a part of full code. But at the moment I can return only first "Peter" with using "func first(where predicate: (Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Element?". But I need all elements with name "Peter".

Comment: Then update your question so it becomes clear what you have and what you needs help with.

Comment: Have you tried [filter()](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/dictionary/2995335-filter)?

Comment: Yes. And after that I have array of dictionaries with key-value where key name is Peter. This is the point where I stuck.
I need to move forward and get values. But I can't because filter returns Bool.

Comment: Do show how you have decoded your JSON. The easiest way would be to use structs and Codable.

Comment: I edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Codable Model of the JSON**

```
struct Welcome: Codable {
   let data: [Datum]
   let view: [String]
}

struct Datum: Codable {
    let name: String
    let features: Feature?
    let data: Data?
}
struct Data: Codable {
    let age, hobby: String
    let job: String? 
}
struct Feature: Codable {let age, hobby: String}
```

**Decode the JSON**

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let decodedObject = try! decoder.decode(Welcome.self, from: JSON)
let filterdPeter = decodedObject.data.filter {$0.name == "Peter"}.map({$0.data})

filterdPeter.forEach {print($0)}
```

Comment: Confirms @jshivam's solution works. If you want the whole fragment just remove the .map({$0.data}) part

Answer (score 0):

```
if let json = object as? [String: Any],
  let dataJSON = json["data"] as? [[String: Any]] { //in the data field you have an array of dictionaries, maybe this is what you're stuck on?
    dataJSON.forEach { jsonElement in
        if let name = jsonElement["name"] as? String, name == "Peter" {
            print(jsonElement["data"])
        }             
    }
}
```

Comment: No. Excuse me that my post is not understandable. Check please comments under the main post. And thank you for your answer.